# SSIS - output stored procedure result to e-mail

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send Mail Task based on output from Execute SQL Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556276/send-mail-task-based-on-output-from-execute-sql-task)

Goal: E-mail output of a stored procedure to someone using SSIS.

I have a simple stored procedure that returns the count of a column. I would like to e-mail that value in e-mail.

What I think I should do: I should create a package in SSRS. Bring in Execute SQL TASK and E-Mail task. For the execute SQL task, connect to server/database. Type in EXEC proc cmd. Connect that to e-mail.

In the stored procedure I have declared a variable called `@COUNT` and inside the select statement, I have

```
SELECT @Count = COUNT(FIELD_A)....
FROM blah blah....
WHere blah blah.....

SELECT @Count
```

When I execute that procedure, I get a count assigned to `@Count` variable. I would like to make a variable in SSIS and assign it the output value of the procedure. Use that variable and somehow e-mail value of that variable with a custom message. I will be making this a automated job so this package will run everyday at some time and an e-mail with count value should be sent.

I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: It's a **stored** procedure - a procedure **stored** inside SQL Server (it has nothing to do with a "store" ...)

Comment: haha...I am not sure how to response to that except, :FACE PALM: on my part.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) instead of SSIS? You did not mention SSIS in your goal ... Not that SSIS won't work, but I think a simple procedure call will be easier for you.

Comment: Hi that sounds like a worthy alternative. But, I would like to do this in SSIS package as it will be easier for others to follow/make changes. I will edit my goal to include SSIS package. Nonetheless, this is something cool you pointed out. Might come handy some day.

Comment: You can still invoke your sproc from SSIS, but send the email via sp_send_dbmail. Then you don't need to wire the results in SSIS.

Comment: I was reading the remarks and it says something about database mail needs to be enabled? Is that something enabled automatically or do I need to get a DBA involved?

Comment: I don't know your abilities, but Googling how to do that should point you into the right direction, e.g. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/